# Exclude Shortcode from search result - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my new WordPress site, when I search for any key word, result showing Shortcodes as well. I don't know how to hide/block these codes. I am not pro in WP site.

URL: http://www.peakalpha.com/?s=testi

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think in homepage your theme is using visual composer.
So, First of all, you need to check your theme's settings. your theme is provided any settings for the search page. because in your home page's visual composer data are broken in the search page.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in functions.php

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_kses_post');
```

but same sure than functionality wont affect after removing that script tags

Better way is to add scripts in .js files instead of content pages in wp-admin

Comment: Added in functions.php, but same result. any other suggestion?

Comment: $content = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', the_content());echo $content;

Comment: this is the php replace function, you need to try it in search template, instead of loading "the_content()" directly, replace the script tags and load the content